Invoking Java Methods from C++, class not found
I was experimenting with how to invoke the Methods from C++, I got this far:
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

// Function to create the JVM and call the sayHi method
void callJavaSayHi() {
    // Options to initialize the JVM
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    options[0].optionString = const_cast<char *>("-Djava.class.path=.");

    // JVM initialization arguments
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    // Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
    JavaVM *jvm;
    // Pointer to native interface
    JNIEnv *env;

    // Create the JVM
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res != JNI_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create JVM: " << res << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        std::cout << "JVM created successfully" << std::endl;
    }

    // Find the Java class
    jclass helloWorldClass = env->FindClass("HelloWorld");
    if (helloWorldClass == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to find HelloWorld class" << std::endl;
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        std::cout << "HelloWorld class found" << std::endl;
    }
 }

But somehow the env->FindClass("HelloWorld") couldn't return the pointer for the class. I get "Failed to find HelloWorld class".
The java class is a simple:
public class HelloWorld {
    // Java method to be called from C++
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hello from Java!");
    }
}

My file structure is like this:
-HelloWorld.class
-HelloWorld.java
-InvokeJavaMethod.cpp

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

"could return the pointer for the class." -> "could not return the pointer for the class." ? ANd please be precise about what actually happens. You get output "Failed to find HelloWorld class" ?

maybe the working directory is not what you think it is. You can try to std::ifstream x{"HelloWorld.java"}; to get the paths right, or at least rule out that mistake

Consider adding -verbose:class to your VM options to debug class loading issues.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah I'm getting "Failed to find HelloWorld class". I just started experimenting with JNI

You need to print the exception. You aren't printing the exception. So you don't know what the exception was. So you can't tell us what the exception was. So we don't know what the exception was. So fix that.

@Yksisarvinen The exception that is pending that caused FindClass() to fail and return zero. This is extremely basic JNI programming.

@user207421 How can I print the exception?

See the ExceptionOccurred and ExceptionDescribe  JNI functions

I printed the exception it says: HelloWorld has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0),

Well there's your problem :D

Apparently my JAVA_HOME is jdk-17 while my java -version is 21

Moral: when you get an error, print the error. Not just some text of your own devising saying "it didn't work". The information content of that is 1 bit. The actual error tells all.

The issue was that my the Java version I compiled it with, was not the same as the one I was including in the linker:
g++ -o InvokeJavaMethod InvokeJavaMethod.cpp -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -L"%JAVA_HOME%\lib" -ljvm

The JAVA_HOME was jdk-17 and the javac was jdk-21.
